# Authentication Mechanisms on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication

We are developing a Saas application on AWS and were looking for ways to store application user login credentials on AWS. User volume will grow quite a lot and would be in thousands presumably. I looked at IAM too but looks like it has a limit of 5000 user profiles whcih we might exhaust down the line.

I dont want to store these on RDS in even a hashed form.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS Cognito user pools to save your application users. It will allow your web/mobile app users to sign up and sign in.

Have a look at [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html)

Answer (score 2):

IAM is for your AWS account users, not for your application users. It sounds like [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) might be what you're looking for.

> Amazon Cognito lets you easily add user sign-up and sign-in to your mobile and web apps. With Amazon Cognito, you also have the options to authenticate users through social identity providers such as Facebook, Twitter, or Amazon, with SAML identity solutions, or by using your own identity system

Comment: Thanks. But can we do a custom user registration and account creation using congnito? In that case, where does it store the user credentials?

Comment: Yes you can. Cognito works fine both on the server and client side. Credentials are stored with AWS, abstracted away from your own technical stack. I would recommend reading up on the introduction to the service and taking a look at the documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/dev-resources/